# calculate descriptive statistics in pandas dataframe based on a condition cyclically

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame with more than 100 thousands of rows. Index represents the time and two columns represents the sensor data and the condition.
When the condition becomes 1, I want to start calculating score card (average and standard deviation) till the next 1 comes. This needs to be calculated for the whole dataset.

Here is a picture of the DataFrame for a specific time span:

[image]

What I thought is to iterate through index and items of the df and when condition is met I start to calculate the descriptive statistics.

```
cycle = 0

for i, row in df_b.iterrows():
if row['condition'] == 1:
    print('Condition is changed')
    cycle += 1
    print('cycle: ', cycle)
    #start = ?
    #end = ?
    #df_b.loc[start:end]
```

I am not sure how to calculate `start` and `end` for this DataFrame. The `end` will be the `start` for the next cycle. Additionally, I think this iteration is not the optimal one because it takes a bit of long time to iterate. I appreciate any idea or solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe start out with getting the rows where condition == 1:

```
cond_1_df = df.loc[df['condition'] == 1]
```

This dataframe will only contain the rows that meet your condition (being 1).
From here on, you can access the timestamps pairwise, meaning that the first element is beginning and second element is end, sketched below:

```
former = 0
stamp_pairs = []
df = cond_1_df.reset_index()  # make sure indexes pair with number of rows
for index, row in df.iterrows():

    if former != 0:
        beginning = former
        end = row["timestamp"]
        former = row["timestamp"]
    else:
        beginning = 0
        end = row["timestamp"]
        former = row["timestamp"]
    stamp_pairs.append([beginning, end])
```

This should give you something like this:

[[stamp0, stamp1], [stamp1,stamp2], [stamp2, stamp3]...]

for each of these pairs, you can again create a df containing only the subset of rows where stamp_x < timestamp < stamp_x+1:

```
time_cond_df = df.loc[(df['timestamp'] > stamp_x) & (df['timestamp'] < stamp_x+1)]
```

Finally, you get one time_cond_df per timestamp tuple, on which you can perform your score calculations.

Just make shure that your timestamps are comparable with operators ">" and "<"! We can't tell since you did not explicate how you produced the timestamps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Timestamps are datetime format and compatible with comparison operators. I think where you reset the index, you should assign it to a new dataframe not the original one. I did this in my code and sounds working. The first tupple has 4 hours difference and when I filter dataframe based on the first tuple time difference, I get a bigger dataframe compared to the original one. any idea?

Comment: Good point. What is your expectation on the variance of time intervals between conditions of 1? When do you add new records? Is it fully random or recorded every x seconds? or only on sensor output change? Is the sensor value causally related to the change in condition? Then you might want to use only x records before the change in condition to 1, e.g. 100 records, something like min(100,  y) where y is the number of records between conditions of 1.

Comment: The data is recorded every 1s. But because I observed two value of 1 in "condition" column after each other, I interpolated the data for 1.5s. So let's consider every 1.5 s we have new data. Yes the sensor value is related to the condition but it is not happened on a regular basis.

Comment: I think this is a question of data interpretation. For example if you have a constant reading of a temperature sensor, you might recognize a constant increase triggering the condition to become 1. If your CPU takes 4 hours to heat up till it throttles, your cooler might be ok, if it heats up in seconds your cooler may be broken.  I think one needs additional information what the sensor output and the condition mean, because data interpretation is always dependent on use case.